# Using pyspark to read a Cassandra table has error: too many open files

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

I was trying to read a column named "machine" in a Cassandra table named "c_parser_feature" using pyspark. Here is my code:

> df = read_cassandra(args.keyspace,
>   args.table).select(args.key).distinct()

However, the code failed:

> File
>   "/home/hadoop/app/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 319, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o57.showString. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 169 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   169.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 536, 11.11.11.66, executor 5): java.io.IOException: Exception during execution of SELECT "machine"
>   FROM "tahoe"."c_parser_feature" WHERE token("sha256") > ? AND
>   token("sha256") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: Not enough replicas available
>   for query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 required but only 0 alive)

The Cassandra table c_parser_feature has unicode information which I think may be the cause. Because the other table that contains only string information can be read fine.
Here is the information about the table c_parser_feature:

> ➜  spark git:(master) ✗ nodetool cfstats tahoe.c_parser_feature -H
>
> Keyspace: tahoe
>
> ```
> Read Count: 0
> Read Latency: NaN ms.
> Write Count: 0
> Write Latency: NaN ms.
> Pending Flushes: 0
>     Table: c_parser_feature
>     SSTable count: 2591
>     Space used (live): 403.33 GB
>     Space used (total): 403.33 GB
>     Space used by snapshots (total): 0 bytes
>     Off heap memory used (total): 268.18 MB
>     SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.2275302195145885
>     Number of keys (estimate): 12050411
>     Memtable cell count: 0
>     Memtable data size: 0 bytes
>     Memtable off heap memory used: 0 bytes
>     Memtable switch count: 0
>     Local read count: 0
>     Local read latency: NaN ms
>     Local write count: 0
>     Local write latency: NaN ms
>     Pending flushes: 0
>     Bloom filter false positives: 0
>     Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
>     Bloom filter space used: 30.86 MB
>     Bloom filter off heap memory used: 30.84 MB
>     Index summary off heap memory used: 10.04 MB
>     Compression metadata off heap memory used: 227.3 MB
>     Compacted partition minimum bytes: 73 bytes
>     Compacted partition maximum bytes: 16.63 MB
>     Compacted partition mean bytes: 118.48 KB
>     Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
>     Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
>     Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
>     Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
> ```

Here is the system log from Cassandra:

> ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-38] 2017-10-27 15:12:57,126
>   JVMStabilityInspector.java:117 - JVM state determined to be unstable. 
>   Exiting forcefully due to: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/cassandra/data/tahoe/c_parser_feature-a68ad250a94611e7bd63a3972fd6016a/tahoe-c_parser_feature-ka-128662-Index.db
>   (Too many open files)

Here is my limit on number of files:

> ```
> ➜  spark git:(master) ✗ ulimit -n
> 655360
> ```

Here is number of files in /data/cassandra/data/tahoe/c_parser_feature-a68ad250a94611e7bd63a3972fd6016a/:

> ➜  spark git:(master) ✗ ls
>   /data/cassandra/data/tahoe/c_parser_feature-a68ad250a94611e7bd63a3972fd6016a/
>   | wc -l
>
> 20724

Comment: Cassandra runs under the same user for which you check limit?

Comment: Yes. It is under the same user.